# .htaccess redirection beatify URL/ Hide structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

My goal is to take an URL of the format

```
www.mydomain.com(/dir1)?(/dir2)?/(index.php|login.php)((:?\?code=)[a-Z0-9]+)?
```

Force the browser url change into:

```
www.mydomain.com/(home|welcomepage)/code/%1/
```

a much simplified example would be:

```
 www.mydomain.com/dir1/dir2/index.php?code=khkdh239
```

changes to :

```
 www.mydomain.com/home/code/khkdh239/
```

and redirects **internally** to

```
 www.mydomain.com/dir1/dir2/index.php?code=khkdh239
```

Here is one of many of my attempts;

```
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$  # I was experimenting with simple urls, no ?code=....
#RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^(?:dir1/)?(?:dir2/)?(?:login.php)$ /welcomepage/? [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^.*welcomepage.*$ code/login.php? [QSA,L]
```

Observations based on the results of my attempts:

1. The rule

   ```
   RewriteRule ^welcomepage/$ code/login.php? [QSA,L]
   ```

   does not redirect, so I used `^.*welcomepage.*$`.
2. The rule

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(?:dir1/)?(?:dir2/)?(?:login.php)$ /welcomepage/? [R=301,NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^.*welcomepage.*$ code/login.php? [QSA,L]
   ```

   Redirects to `www.domain.com/welcomepage/` but the internal redirection fails.
3. The rules

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(?:dir1/)?(?:dir2/)?(?:login.php)$ /welcomepage/? [R=301,NC]
   RewriteRule ^.*welcomepage.*$ code/login.php? [QSA,L]
   ```

   redirects to the second link but not to the first.
4. I added in the site's configuration a [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) file setting however it does not seem to work.
5. At some point the redirections were working, however file uploads etc were failing (`POST` operation).

## Questions:

1. **Does anyone know how to achieve the hidden redirection, without loosing functionality, such as file upload.**
2. If not, does anyone know how to
   setup properly a redirect log, so that I can debug the redirections
   more efficiently?

PS: I know there are multiple questions in stack overflow, and I have been going over them as well as through the manual for .htaccess redirection, however there always seems to be some issue.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: code is sub directory of the directory in which .htaccess is located.

Comment: Is .htaccess is placed right under `DOCUMENT_ROOT`?

Comment: It is placed under dir1. Should it be placed in the directory above?

Comment: I think I managed to fix it by moving the `.htaccess` to the root directory. Thank you!. I will make sure everything is working tomorrow.

Comment: Yes indeed as per your rules it should be placed right under `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final unrefined solution was a combination of [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava), [hjpotter92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/hjpotter92) and mine.

I am going to provide the `.httaccess` code in case anyone faces similar problems.

Important: all the redirection Flags can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html) ([NC,R,P,L] etc).

## Why were most of the redirection not working

Because my .htacces file was located in `/{ROOT_DIRECTORY_OF_SITE}/dir1/` instead of `/{ROOT_DIRECTORY_OF_SITE}/`

## How to achieve the hidden redirection for GET urls

To accomplish this I followed [hjpotter92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/hjpotter92) advice and I checked if for all `GET` requests for which `THE_REQUEST` was following a specific regular expression. In those cases the real address was forwarded to a fake one. I used `R=301`, which is permanent redirection, only when I was sure it was correct. While debugging use `R=302` and a private browsing.

```
# Redirect dir1/dir2/login.php?code=password  to fake address mydomain.com/signup/?code=password
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET\ /?(?:dir1/)?(?:dir2/)?login\.php\?code=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /signup/%1/ [R=301,L]

#Redirect fake address mydomain.com/signup/?code=pasword internaly to real address
RewriteRule ^signup/([^/]+)/$ /dir1/dir2/login.php?code=$1 [NC,L]
```

## How to achieve the hidden redirection for POST urls without loosing functionality, such as file upload.

Here I had to be a bit creative. In the form for file upload I changed the redirection  to point towards a *fake*, *beatified* `url`.

For example to send the post request to `mydomain.com/signup/send-mail/#login` I used:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="/signup/send-mail/#login" id="login">
```

And then in the `.htaccess` file I redirected the fake `url` request to a real one.

```
RewriteRule ^signup/email-sent/ /dir1/dir2/login.php#login [NC,P]
```

The `[P]` flag is equivalent to `[L]` but it also allows POST data redirection as it works as a proxy. The `[L]` flag simply tells the system not to continue downwards in the `.htaccess` file as this will be the last redirection (in simple words, for details refer to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html)).

## .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes 
DirectoryIndex ./dir1/dir2/index.php

RewriteEngine on

# Redirect dir1/dir2/login.php?code=password  to fake address mydomain.com/signup/?code=password
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET\ /?(?:dir1/)?(?:dir2/)?login\.php\?code=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /signup/%1/ [R=301,L]

#Redirect fake address mydomain.com/signup/?code=pasword internaly to real address
RewriteRule ^signup/([^/]+)/$ /dir1/dir2/login.php?code=$1 [NC,L]


# Redirect dir1/dir2/login.php to fake address mydomain.com/signup/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET\ /?(?:dir1/)?(?:code/)?login\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /signup/ [R=302,L]

#Redirect fake address mydomain.com/signup/ internaly to real address
RewriteRule ^signup/$ /dir1/dir2/login.php [NC,L]


# Redirect dir1/dir2/index.php?code=password to fake address mydomain.com/home/?code=password
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET\ /?(?:dir1/)?(?:code/)?index\.php\?code=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /home/%1/ [R=302,L]

# Redirect the fake address mydomain.com/home/?code=password to a real one, internaly
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]+)/$ /dir1/dir2/index.php?code=$1 [NC,L]

# Redirect dir1/dir2/index.php to fake address mydomain.com/home/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET\ /?(?:dir1/)?(?:code/)?index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /home/ [R=302,L]

# Redirect the fake address mydomain.com/home/ to a real one, internaly
RewriteRule ^home/$ /dir1/dir2/index.php [NC,L]


# Redirect the fake address mydomain.com/signup/email-sent/ to a realone
RewriteRule ^signup/email-sent/ /dir1/dir2/login.php#login [NC,P]

# Redirect the fake address mydomain.com/home/file-uploaded/ to a realone
RewriteRule ^home/file-uploaded/ /dir1/dir2/index.php#page-demo-upload [NC,P]
```

A big thank you to everyone who answered my post and helped me reach this version for the `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1):

For redirecting your URLs to pretty ones, you'd check `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET\ (?:/dir1)?(?:/dir2)?/index\.php\?code=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /home/code/%1/ [R=301,L]
```

Next, you want the friendly URL to internally address some other script:

```
RewriteRule ^home/code/([^/]+)/?$ /dir1/dir2/index.php?code=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It works in general, however when I am uploading files since it is a post action and not get the redirection does not work and the original URL appears. Is there a way to hide the IP then too, without though losin functionality?